# QGIS 3.10: Evaluate default values (data source preference) not staying checked on?

Tags: qgis-3, calculate-values

Anyone having trouble with "evaluate default values" in QGIS 3.10.1 preferences, under "Data Sources"?

When I click the check box and then "OK", I go back to preferences it's unchecked! And default values are not being evaluated... I am a QGIS novice, so not qualified to call "bug"!

When I add new features, I want the field calculations in the table to fill automatically. Is this the way to go about it?

I don't want to use virtual fields as I want the calculated fields to be part of the geopackage/shapefile. I'd like the values to update as I modify features.

Comment: I have seen that, when trying to define provider side default values in GeoPackages. Seems to me not fully implemented. I don't know if it is a bug, but maybe yes. I choose defining triggers in the file database. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/344633/133276

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. I hadn't considered SpatiaLite triggers because I didn't know about them! They might be just what I need, learning about them now from this site: http://www.lifeingis.com/adding-triggers-to-spatialite-databases-in-qgis/